# Joomla Clean URL for articles (Why adding category name)

Tags: php, url, joomla, clean-urls

I'm beginner in joomla and have very simple question

Why Joomla adding the **category name** and repeat the article sef i have article with the name of **Privacy Policy** and sef is **privacy-policy**
when i hit the url

> site.com/privacy-policy

it's auto convert into

> site.com/privacy-policy/uncategorised/privacy-policy

but i need **site.com/privacy-policy** this URL

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a menu item in the root (top-level of the menu) pointing to the article, and you'll only get the alias you want.

If you don't want it in a menu, simply create a new menu type, call it "hidden" or something that helps you remember it's not to be shown, and place the link there.

Otherwise there's plenty of extensions that will do this for you, but usually for a simple site it's faster and more future-proof this way.